# Fails to read InputStream

Tags: java, android

I'm using the following code to read `InputStream` from `Runtime.Exec()`.

**CODE :**

```
private String inputstreamReader(String[] shellinput) {
        InputStream inputstream = null;
        String isrval = null;
        System.out.println("Entering inputstreamReader");
        try {
            inputstream = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(shellinput)
                    .getInputStream();

            System.out.println("Tried getRuntime().exec  :: "+inputstream.read());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed getRuntime().exec");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
        try {
            isrval = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader).readLine();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("TEMPfile is "+isrval);
        return isrval;

    }
```

But it returns :

**STACKTRACE :**

```
02-28 19:34:20.663: I/System.out(20892): Entering inputstreamReader
02-28 19:34:20.694: I/System.out(20892): Tried getRuntime().exec  :: -1
02-28 19:34:20.694: I/System.out(20892): TEMPfile is null
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: What are you trying to run in your exec? Are you sure it's a valid command? Also, you're aware that you're reading the first byte of output when you do inputstream.read(), right? That's a bug in this code, regardless of what you expect from the rest of it.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, your exec likely fails without any output, as you can see from this line:

```
Tried getRuntime().exec  :: -1
```

The "-1" means you've reached the end of the stream. This causes

```
new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader).readLine();
```

to return null, and that's what you see:

```
TEMPfile is null
```